# Export Matches array object to CSV in Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a powershell script to find particular instances and then export them to CSV.  Here's an example of the way the code works

```
$items = "Hello Tim", "Hola Bob", "Hello Susan" 
$filter = $items | Select-String -Pattern "Hello"
$filter | Select-Object Line, Matches | Export-Csv "C:\log.csv"
Invoke-Item "C:\log.csv"
```

When I run the `Select-Object` in PS, it's nicely formatted info like this:

[image: powershell]

However, when I export to CSV, it exports the whole object and writes it as the following string: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]`

[image: csv export]

How can I get it to export just the first match or a listing of all matches into a single field when writing to CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly note that Matches is an array which may create issues exporting to a csv.
Try joining the array into a string with a chosen delimiter.  I used "::" in my example.

```
$filter | Select Line, @{Expression={$_.Matches -join "::"}; Label="Matches"} | Export-Csv "C:\log.csv"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using a PSObject:

```
$items = "Hello Tim", "Hola Bob", "Hello Susan" 
$filter = $items | Select-String -Pattern "Hello"
$filter | % {New-Object PSObject -property @{
  Line = $_.Line
  Matches = $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value}
} | Export-Csv "C:\log.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```